# How to get elements in the vector into ArrayList

Tags: java, pdf, arraylist, vector

I have code that creates pdf document, after it gets acroform fields from it and saves them in vector.

```
PDFDocument pdfDocument = new PDFDocument(pdfPath, null);
        AcroForm acroForm = pdfDocument.getAcroForm();
        Vector fieldList = acroForm.getFieldList();
        System.out.println("fieldList: " + fieldList);
```

Sysout returns this:

```
[[Field FullName=amtApprvd_1_2 Type=Tx], [Field FullName=percentIrateInit_1_2 Type=Tx], [Field FullName=borrowerName Type=Tx]]
```

Now I want to save field name(for example, amtApprvd_1_2) in ArrayList. How I could do that?

I was able to use enum and iterator but I could only save them as object, which has both field name and type. But I want only field name in ArrayList. Please advice.

API for AcroForm is from com.qoppa.pdf.form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know the API of `AcroForm` and the `getFieldList()` method, but something like this:

```
Vector<Field> fieldList = acroForm.getFieldList();
ArrayList<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<>(fieldList.size());
for (Field field : fieldList)
    fieldNames.add(field.getFullName());
```

This assumes that `getFieldList()` returns a `Vector<Field>`, not just a raw `Vector`.

Comment: API for AcroForm is from com.qoppa.pdf.form. I will try your version. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Andreas!

Answer (score 1):

```
   Vector<String> yourvector = new Vector<String>();
   ArrayList names = new ArrayList(); 
   for(FieldListObj list  : fieldList){
   names.add(list.getname());
   }
```

you can do this easily with above approach. .im just assuming 
`FieldListObj` is your class name and you have a getName method to get the name of the field.

Comment: Thanks for quick response but as I said I was able to get as Object but I want to save filed name only in ArrayList, not whole object.

Comment: its very difficult to give the correct answer since you havent given proper information with the code.

Comment: I am sorry, I added API to the problem description. Andreas gave me correct answer. Thanks again.

Comment: i gave you the answer ?.